# How to get p-values only in significance test in R

Tags: r, dataframe, p-value, significance

I m working on significance tests in R, especially `wilcox.test`.
I check for example column A of my dataframe `data`.

```
wilcox.test(data$A, mu=3)
```

Afterwards I get a lot of data and text in the console. Is there a posibility to get only the `p.value`? I hope it will be a bit more clear, when I check the other columns too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a `list`, so extract with `$` or `[[`

```
out <- wilcox.test(data$A, mu=3)
out$p.value
```

We can get more info by checking the `str`

```
str(out)
```

---

If there are more columns, loop over the columns with `lapply/sapply` and extract the `p.value`

```
sapply(data[c("A", "B")], function(x) wilcox.test(x, mu = 3)$p.value)
```